# Choosing a random amount of balls from an urn using another urn

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $2$ Urns, the first urn has $U_{1,b}$ black balls, $U_{1,w}$ white balls and $d$ balls that were chosen from the second urn which has: $U_{2,b}$ black balls and $U_{2,w}$ white balls.

And we know that $n \leq U_{1,b} + U_{1,w} +d $

Calculate the expectation of the number of black balls that were chosen if we choose $n$ balls (randomly) from urn $\#1$. You do not return the balls you take.

My try:

Because it is without returns, I cannot use binomial distribution.. so I thought about Hyper-Geometric distribution, I hope it is correct:

$N = U_{1,b} + U_{1,w} + d ~ , ~ D = U_{1,b} ~ , ~ n = n$ so:
$E[X = \text{black balls}] = \frac{nD}{N} = \frac{n \cdot U_{1,b}}{U_{1,b} +U_{1,w} + d}$

Now we want to calculate $d$ however I am stuck + I am not sure even if my way is correct...

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I would assume $d$ would be a "known quantity", that is, an input to the problem, not something you have to calculate. So it would be OK for $d$ to appear in the answer. But it is possible that there are more than $U_{1,b}$ black balls in the first urn when you draw the $n$ balls, because some of the $d$ balls you added might have been black. That's the tricky part of the question.

Comment: @DavidK Actually I think it's ok to have $d$ in your answer because they said "use these unknowns in your answer" (I did not write that - sorry)

Comment: That makes sense. Clearly you don't need to eliminate $d$. But you do need to account for the possible extra black balls.